# Passing DateTime in the where class as a parameter C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to pass two `DateTime` parameters to an SQL statement. This is what I am trying to pass along with the C# code:

```
string command = @"SELECT EMP._name AS employername, EMP._contact AS employercontact, EMP.employerid, EMP.firmid 
                 FROM EMPLOYER AS EMP 
                 LEFT JOIN SERVICE AS SERV 
                 ON EMP.employerid = SERV.employerid 
                 WHERE SERV._dateRecordCreated >= @yearStartDate 
                 AND SERV._dateRecordCreated  <= @yearEndDate 
                 ORDER BY employername;";
```

And this is how I am passing the paramaters:

```
DateTime yearStartDt = new DateTime(2015, 1,1);
DateTime yearEndDt = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yearStartDate", yearStartDt);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yearEndDate", yearEndDt);
```

I keep getting SQL Exception 137

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result...)

Comment: Remove the quotes around `@yearStartDate` and `@yearEndDate` in the SQL. The values are not substituted in -- no string quoting is necessary.

Comment: I've never passed params like that, only this way: `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearStartDate", yearStartDt);` - basically saying try like that instead of passing the type

Comment: @JeroenMostert I removed the quotations marks.  Now I am getting SQL Exception 137 instead.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Per @RobScott, your call is also incorrect -- use `Parameters.Add`, not `Parameters.AddWithValue`.

Comment: @Steve Sql Server 2012

Comment: @JeroenMostert I edited the post to reflect the changes that I've made.  It is still throwing SQL exception 137.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% certain your column type is `datetime`?

Comment: `FROM EMPLOYER AS EMP` I don't think you can use the `AS` keyword like this. Maybe I'm wrong. Try `FROM EMPLOYER EMP`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy it's a valid way to use `AS`. The `AS` could be ommited though, only stating `FROM EMPLOYER EMP`

Comment: Any reason you keep giving people *numbers* rather than the *message*? Error 137 is "Must declare the scalar variable [variable]". This suggests SQL Server doesn't see you pass the parameters, which is no surprise, since the call is still wrong. Use `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yearStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = yearStartDt`.

Comment: @MXD Ahh. I've never used the `AS` keyword in this context. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Comment: Can you show your entire code block? The connection being instantiated and opened, the SqlCommand object etc?

Comment: can you add more code related to `sqlCommand`

Comment: One side note: If you are dealing with `DateTime` the way you do it, you'll miss all data happened on the very last day of the year. `2015-12-31 09:00:00` is greater than `2015-12-31`

Comment: Well I feel stupid now.  I was passing the parameters after executing the SqlDataReader, that was why it wasn't seeing the parameters being passed.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Never mind, everybody has done such things... Happy coding!

Comment: That's pretty much what I was expecting you were doing. Glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yearStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@yearStartDate"].Value = yearStartDt;
```

Comment: You should explain *why* this answers the question - `Add` expects a type as the second argument, *not* a value. It also returns the new SqlParameter object so there is no reason to retrieve it again with `["@paramname"]

Comment: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@yearStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = yearStartDt;`